# Java 8 lambda null list to empty check

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to do `null` check for the list of values and change it to empty if the value is `null.`I am getting null as one of the list of value in x.getSomeCall().The null value is not getting added as empty list in the new list

```
public class Example{
     private List<Test> test;
     //setter
     //getter
}

public class Test{
    private List<Test2> test2;
     //setter
     //getter
}

public class Test2{
    private String name;
    //setter
    //getter
}

public static void main(String args[]){
```

Example example=new Example();
example.setTest(test);

```
    List<Test> test=new ArrayList<>();
    Test t=new Test();
    t.setTest2(test);
    Test t1=new Test();
    Test t2=new Test();
    test.add(t);
    test.add(t1);

    List<Test2> test=new ArrayList<>();
    Test2 t=new Test2();
    test.add(t);
    test.add(null); // I want to get these value as empty list along with the 1st Value in a new list

//Imperative Programming
for(Example ex:example.getTest()){
System.out.println(ex.getTest2());/It prints t object and a null vale

}


When I tried the same with reactive

List<Test2> t=example.getTest().stream()
                              .flatMap(x -> x.getTest2() == null ? Stream.empty() : x.getTest2().stream())
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(t)// It prints only t object
I was expecting two element on with t object and the other one as empty list[]

}
```

So that later I can do an empty check with the new list

```
 if(isEmpty(example.getTest().stream()
                                  .flatMap(x -> x.getTest2() == null ? Stream.empty() : x.getTest2().stream())
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())))
```

Comment: why not this `result.stream().flatMap(x-> Stream.of(x.getSomeCall())).collect(Collectors.toList()).size()`

Comment: I got the size as 2..How do I iterate this list..I am getting some compile time error while iterating.I am new to Java 8. I want to check the list value..

Comment: @Subham you defined a list called `somecall` but you're not using this in your code... and when I said  "edit your code to ensure it compiles" I was referring to `1stlist` as that's not a valid identifier in Java. Further, I can't seem to digest what you're trying to achieve here so if you could provide some more information in regard to the task at hand that would help me and other people in the same position to understand where you're coming from.

Comment: As said above it is quite unclear what you expect to achieve here without giving us some examples of inputs and expected outputs. What is most confusing to me is the conflict between using ```flatMap``` and somehow expecting that for each list  or null  returned by a getSomeCall() in an input stream value you expect to have one element in the output that represents that list or null. flatMap would simply "melt" all those lists into a simple element stream so that input empty lists won't have any presence in the output... typically if null inputs are accepted they would have the same fate.

Comment: ... in other words if the example input getSomeCall() invocations would return a singleton list (with only one element) for the first input and a null for the second input the most straightforward reasonable output would have only one element. .... if the first input has 5 elements, a second input  is null, a third input is empty and the fourth input has 2 elements the most reasonable output would have 7 elements... the ones present in the first and last inputs.

Comment: Perhaps you mean to keep the input getSomeCall returned lists as they are without flattening them?

Comment: @ValentinRuano  updated  the question

Comment: @Subham what should the list contain?  you keep saying you expect 2 elements.  What are those elements supposed to be?

Comment: @Misha the list should contain one object and an empty list..

Comment: @HadiJ How to get the list for your solution..I am getting the size as two and conetnt with two objects but while assigning the result to new list getting compile time error   List<Test2> t=result.stream().flatMap(x-> Stream.of(x.getSomeCall())).collect(Collectors.toList()));

Comment: So you want as a result an Stream that contains a mix-bag of different element type where every null in the output is transformed into a empty list and all other input elements are left as they are no change whatsoever?

Comment: @Valentin..Yes thats is exactly  I am looking for..

Comment: Could you include the signature of getSomeCall(), can we make any assumption as to what it returns? it seems to be ```List<?> getSomeCall()``` based on what I can read in the question but this is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

It's often simpler and more readable to break up a complex stream step into into multiple simple ones:

```
list1.stream()
     .map(SomeCall::getSomeCall)
     .filter(Objects::nonNull)
     .flatMap(Collection::stream)   // or List::stream if it's a list
     .collect(...)
```

Comment: I am getting the list size as 1.I was expecting list size value as 2..The 1st value with some object and the second one as an empty list

Comment: This should be the accepted answer based on the original question. @Subham please provide a more definitive example of the data you're using that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You could instead find such a `sum` simply using:

```
int size = stList.stream() // variable renamed not to start with numeric
        .mapToInt(st -> Optional.ofNullable(st.getSomeCall()).map(List::size).orElse(0))
        .sum();
```

***Updated with question***:

```
System.out.println(example.getTest().stream() // variable renamed not to start with numeric
        .mapToInt(st -> Optional.ofNullable(st.getTest2()).map(List::size).orElse(0))
        .sum());
```

---

> get the list of value instead of size

If you were to get the `List<Test2>` as a result, your existing code is good enough, though you can also get it as :

```
List<Test2> list = example.getTest().stream()
        .map(a -> a.getTest2() == null ? new ArrayList<Test2>() : a.getTest2())
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @HadiJ because `st.getSomeCall()` could be `null`. if null consider the value as `0` or else the actual size of the `List`.

Comment: How to get the list of value instead of size??

Comment: @Subham Though I've updated the answer seems like the code in the question has been changed a bit, it wouldn't compile now. Make sure to fix it for complete understanding.

Comment: @It gives one element as a result..Dont know why the null value which is supposed to changed in to empty list is not added in to the new list..

Comment: @Subham which null value are you talking about? Please edit the question to make it compile and be clear. Additionally, we've been filtering out the `null` value in our code above.

Comment: @Subham I've edited the code to map null to empty ArrayList in the updated code, what you might be looking for.

Comment: ,Yes I am exactly looking for the scenario which you had mentioned above..Still after implenting your changes..I am getting only one element instead of two element

Comment: @Subham that's why I was asking you to edit your question with correct input such that one can infer whats not working there. Please update the question and share the output you are expecting versus you're actually getting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186453/discussion-between-subham-and-nullpointer).

Comment: Instead of `.map(a -> a.getTest2() == null ? new ArrayList<Test2>() : a.getTest2()) .flatMap(List::stream)`, I’d use `.flatMap(a -> a.getTest2() == null? null: a.getTest2().stream())`, which saves you from unnecessary creating and streaming over empty `ArrayList`s.

Comment: @Holger Well, the OP was insisting on considering the empty `ArrayList` for null cases, that's why that unnecessary creation. In the revisions to the answer, you can notice me initially filtering out the `null`, then I ended up considering them as well as creating an additional overhead on OP's request.

Comment: But that overhead is pointless, as it doesn’t change the result, hence, doesn’t solve the OP’s problem. The OP’s problem seems to be that they are comparing to output of a loop printing unflattened original lists with a Stream operation collecting to a flattened `List<Test2>`. Of course, doing entirely different things may produce entirely different outcome. But it doesn’t help to provide an answer suggesting  to every reader to produce an unnecessary overhead…